# FirestoreDataConverter throws error for Admin SDK but not for JavaScript or NodeJS as client

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a TypeScript file that contains a model class. This model class maps documents in my Firestore. The class could has the following fields:

```js
class MyObject {

  myName: string;
  myAge: number;
  myFriends: Array<string>

  // contructor
}
```

The Firebase API offers a [`FirebaseDataConverter`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.FirestoreDataConverter) to transform document data in an object of that class and vica versa. I added this to my model class:

```js
class MyObject {

  //...

  static firestoreConverter: firebase.firestore.FirestoreDataConverter<MyObject> = {

    toFirestore: function (myObject: MyObject): firebase.firestore.DocumentData {
      return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject));
    }

    fromFirestore: function (snapshot: firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot<MyObject>, options: firebase.firestore.SnapshotOptions): MyObject {
            let docData = snapshot.data(options);
            let data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(docData));
            // call constructor with fields from data
            return new MyObject(...);
    }
  }
}
```

Now I can add this converter to a collection reference:

```js
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

// initialize firebase etc.

const firestore = firebase.firestore();
const myCollectionRef = firestore.collection("MyCollection").withConverter(MyObject.firestoreConverter);
```

With this mechanism I retreive directly MyObjects and do not have to parse them each time I read, write, etc. them.

So far this worked fine for the JavaScript Web library. I want to use this mechanism now with the Admin SDK. First everything seems fine:

```js
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

// initialize firebase etc.

const firestore = admin.firestore();
const myCollectionRef = firestore.collection("MyCollection").withConverter(MyObject.firestoreConverter);
```

But if I get an document and try to access the content with `doc.data()` it says `Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'MyObject'.`

```js
myCollectionRef.doc("myId").get().then(snapshot => {
  let myObject: MyObject = snapshot.data();
});
```

Does anybody know what do I have to change to receive `MyObject` and not `unknown`?

## EDIT

It seems like it is not supported as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects). Toggle 'Web' to see the JavaScript example. Toggle 'Node.js' to see that it just uses Plain JavaScript objects. I still wonder why it is not possible. Isn't the Firestore object form the same type?!

Answer (score 1):

For now I can manually do the stuff the `FirestoreDataConverter` does but I hope the Admin SDK will support the `FirestoreDataConverter` in the future.

```js
myCollectionRef.doc("myId").get().then(snapshot => {
  let data = snapshot.data();
  let myObject = new MyObject(/* data fields ... */);
});
```